# POST llega vacío aunque lo mando en el cuerpo slim framework 3

Tags: php, javascript, typescript, ionic3, slim3

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en ionic y al momento de enviar dos datos al servidor no llegan, se quedan vacíos, con Postman la petición sí sirve y sí inserta los datos en la base de datos pero cuando intento hacerlo desde la aplicación me manda el error de "Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'Longitud' cannot be null", imprimí los valores en el error y salen vacíos. Esas columnas no pueden ser nulas.

Esta es mi clase cliente.php en donde recibo los datos e intento insertar:

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use \Slim\Http\UploadedFile;

$configuration = [
    'settings' => [
        'displayErrorDetails' => true,
    ],
];
$c = new \Slim\Container($configuration);
$app = new \Slim\App($c);

$container = $app->getContainer();
$container['upload_directory'] = 'photos/';

$app->options('/{routes:.+}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    return $response;
});

$app->add(function ($req, $res, $next) {
    $response = $next($req, $res);
    return $response
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization')
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS');
});

$app->post('/api/georeferencia', function (Request $request, Response $response) use ($app){
    $latitud = $request->getParam('latitud');
    $longitud = $request->getParam('longitud');

    $sql = "INSERT INTO zacatecas_digital.ReportesBacheo (Longitud, Latitud) VALUES (:longitud, :latitud)";

    try {
        $db = new db();
        $db = $db->conectDB();
        $resultado = $db->prepare($sql);

        $resultado->bindParam(':longitud', $longitud);
        $resultado->bindParam(':latitud', $latitud);

        $resultado->execute();

        echo json_encode("Campos agregados");

        $resultado = null;
        $db = null;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error" : {"text":'.$e->getMessage().'}';
    }
});

// Catch-all route to serve a 404 Not Found page if none of the routes match
// NOTE: make sure this route is defined last
$app->map(['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'PATCH'], '/{routes:.+}', function($req, $res) {
    $handler = $this->notFoundHandler; // handle using the default Slim page not found handler
    return $handler($req, $res);
});
```

Y así lo envío desde la aplicación en ionic:

```
enviarDatos() {  
    let postData = new FormData();
    postData.append("latitud", this.latitud);
    postData.append("longitud", this.longitud);
    alert("latitud: " + this.latitud + " y longitud: "+ this.longitud);
    console.log("latitud: "+ this.latitud);
    console.log("latitud: " + this.longitud);
    this.http.post('http://10.0.0.9:8888/ZacatecasDigitalServ/public/api/georeferencia', postData, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'), responseType: 'text'
    })
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
        console.log(error.status);
      });
  }
```

Imprimo varias veces los valores que intento enviar para verificar que no fueran vacíos.

He intentado en vez de usar:

```
$latitud = $request->getParam('latitud');
$longitud = $request->getParam('longitud');
```

Usar esto para obtener los parámetros:

```
$parametros = $request->getParsedBody();
$latitud;
$longitud;
foreach($parametros as $key => $value)
{
    if ($key === 'latitud') {
        $latitud = $value;
    } else {
        $longitud = $value;
    }
}
```

E igualmente funcionó en Postman pero desde la aplicación me sigue mandando error, ¿alguien que me pueda ayudar con esto?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. ¿Cuál es el error que manda? ¿Qué muestra un `var_dump($parametros);`?

Comment: Hola, gracias y perdón por la tardanza, cuando hago var_dump me regresa `array(2) {
  ["latitud"]=>
  string(17) "22.77287160744655"
  ["longitud"]=>
  string(18) "-102.6440581619717"
}` y el error completo que me manda desde la app es `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'Latitud' cannot be null`

Comment: Entonces puedes asignar las variables así: `$latitud=$parametros['latitud']; $longitud=$parametros['longitud'];`

Comment: Ya lo intenté de esa manera y me mandó el mismo error.

Comment: ¿Si imprimes las variables muestra los datos: `22.77287160744655` y `-102.6440581619717`  o parecidos? ¿Las columnas `Longitud` y `Latitud` son adecuadas para recibir ese tipo de valores, de que tipo son dichas columnas?

Comment: Muestra lo mismo, con respecto a la segunda pregunta ya intenté mandándolo como String y Latitud y Longitud como varchar de 256, al igual que con decimal, solo que no recuerdo cuantos decimales le puse, pero con ninguno de los dos funcionaba, se quedaban en nulo.

Comment: Ya lo pude resolver, lo que tuve que hacer es mandarlo como json y cambiar el header.

Comment: Me parece extraño que lo tuvieras como array según el `var_dump` y que luego no recogiese los datos. De todos modos JSON es mucho mejor para enviar/recibir/leer datos.